# Cannot get wheel back on hub after replacing lug bolts

Tags: wheels, hub

I have a 1998 GMC Jimmy. I recently changed the front right tire with a spare. I know I tightened the lugs on both wheels. I went shooting up in the mountain there were a lot of pot holes. I didn't miss all of them. Afterword I drove at speeds up to 75mph on the trip back home. When I exited the freeway and as I turned onto a surface street the was a loud band and my truck was undrivable. When I pulled over to look I saw that the wheel was being held on by only one lug bolt. One was snapped off another two were bent. I got the wheel back on, took one lug nut from each of the other wheels, and drove home. The next day I took the wheel off and replaced the lug bolts. But now I cannot get the wheel back on and I really need my truck. Upon closer examination it appear that the hub is bent in an oval shape preventing the easy mounting of the wheel. How can I get the wheel back on? Very little money and gas.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sorry for your issues ... really about the only way you're going to get it back on if the hub is bent is to replace the hub. You might be able to get one out of a wrecking yard which is viable for a cheap price. Even better, if you have a pick-a-part yard near you where you can pull a hub yourself, it'd probably be cheaper yet.

Comment: No way around replacing the wheel hub.  Even if you could somehow straighten it out, its strength would be compromised and it would be unsafe to drive.

Comment: Broken studs means they were not tight whatever you remember.